# Send Sign Up Form Results to Email Address Via PHP

Tags: phpmailer, php

I have a question about PHP email function, I hope you can help me with this. I have little to no experience in PHP.

Ive set up a web page, where users can submit following info via the HTML form:
Name, Email, Phone, and couple Drop Down Selectors.

I have created an empty form.php and when clicked on submit, it gets connected to that php file. Thing is, I want the results to be mailed to my email address WIHOUT mysql database, as far as I know this is possible with PHP, but I couldnt find any tutorial for this.

Can you give me any pointers or guides please, how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers : ))

EDIT: I forgot to mention, with some PHP tutorials, I managed to send the mail to my email address, and managed to get the email subject correctly, but I couldnt get the results of email in the body of the email sent, body is always empty.

Can you please give me an example script, how I could get the results of this form in the body of message? Most tutorials show how to get $message in the body, but I dont really have any text to send via $message. I simply have couple text fields and couple drop down selectors.

Comment: you should learn about `mail()` function then? No ?

Comment: show code - what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
echo "Mail Sent.";}
else{
echo "Mail not sent";
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
1: soneonelse@example.com; and 'someonelse@example.com are just two different email, like it mentions about the sender and the receiver of the email
So, make sure to change the email I have given above to the email you want to send.

2: If you want to style `<div>` then do something like this:

```
 echo "<div style='color:white; background-color:red; font-size:14px; padding:20px; 
 border:1px solid black;'> Mail Sent</div>";
```

Comment: PHP Noob? more like PHP GOD to me : )) Thank you! Thanks a lot! It may be a simple 5 min answer for you, but you just made my day. Cheers! : ))

Comment: LOL, that is the funniest comment. Don't worry, you'll become master one day, just keep practicing.

Comment: )) It worked out and Im happy with results. But I have couple Noob questions, help me with them if you dont mind please.  

is there a way to show "Mail Sent" thing in DIV, so I could style that?  

2) Whats the difference between "soneonelse@example.com"; and 'someonelse@example.com'; ? they both work right?

Comment: @ArchilChkheidze check my update. remember that `to someone@yahoo.com` is the email of the person, that you will send your email to, but `from me@yahoo.com` is your address, the person will see when he receives your mail

Answer (score 0):

Use `mail()` function:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Details in manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Hi user2270404. Thanks for quick response : ))
with some PHP tutorials, I managed to send the mail to my email address, and managed to get the email subject correctly, but I couldnt get the results of email in the body of the email sent, body is always empty.



     Can you please give me an example script, how I could get the results of this form in the body of message?

     Most tutorials show how to get $message in the body, but I dont really have any text to send via $message. I simply have couple text fields and couple drop down selectors.

Comment: $message is a var, what you put in it is up to you.

Comment: @ArchilChkheidze check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599056/send-sign-up-form-results-to-email-address-via-php/16599469#16599469)